# Where does data sent using xmlhttp.send() get attached in the POST route in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

> I am making an XMLHTTPRequest by calling this function in my javascript code as below

```
ajaxFunctions.ready(ajaxFunctions.ajaxRequest('POST', appUrl+'/new-poll/option-entered', value, function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }));
```

> And then I make the actual xmlhttp request as shown below

```
var ajaxFunctions = {
  ready: function ready (fn) {
      if (typeof fn !== 'function') {
         return;
      }

      if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
         return fn();
      }

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn, false);
  },
  ajaxRequest: function ajaxRequest (method, url, data, callback) {
      console.log('Entered the ajaxRequest function');
      console.log(data);
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            console.log('Making the request');
            callback(xmlhttp.response);
         }
      };

      xmlhttp.open(method, url, true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      xmlhttp.send(data);
  }
};
```

> But when I try to access that data below in the POST route, I get an error because req.body seems to be undefined. However, my res.json works fine, which means I'm not accessing the data I am passing through in the right way.

```
app.route('/new-poll/option-entered')
        .post(function(req, res){
            console.log(req.body.data);
            res.json('Hi I can return data');
        });
};
```

> I acknowledge that this question may just be a duplicate, but I can't seem to find where exactly I'm supposed to access data sent through xmlhttp.send()! After checking the MDN docs, I thought it might be attached to the req.body, but that returns undefined. So where exactly do I find the data attached, or am I making a mistake in the way I am sending the data like setting the wrong RequestHeader?

Comment: Can you please try the value of ```appUrl```? Also, what kind of data are you trying to send?

Comment: Sorry missed out that line, appUrl is set in ajax-functions.js as appUrl = window.location.origin;
I am trying to send plain text data

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the [`body-parser`](https://npmjs.com/package/body-parser) middleware in your Express server. If you want to use `req.body` this needs to be added as middleware to your Express server.

> ### Excerpt from [Express `req.body` docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body)
>
> **req.body**
>
> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as body-parser and multer.

You'll need to install `body-parser` as it does not come as part of the `express` package.

`npm i --save body-parser`

Then add it to your Express Server prior to your routes like below:

```
const express = require('express');
const server = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

server.use(bodyParser.json()); // allows Content-Type application/json
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }); // parses Content-Type x-www-form-urlencoded

// Your routes go here

server.listen(port, () => { console.log(`listening on ${port}`); });
```